# Laravel: Whenever I return a model always return a relationship with it

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, model, eloquent

I have 2 tables:

```
User        |   Doctor
----------  |  ----------
id          |  id
email       |  user_id
name        |  signature
last_name   |  photo
password    |  description
date_birth  |
```

Every `Doctor` is related to a `User`, but every `User` may not be related to a `Doctor`. I did it this way because I didn't want to use Single Table Inheritance and end up with a bunch of `NULL` fields.

Is there a way to make, something like this?

```
// Instead of
$doctor = Doctor::with('User')->find(1);
$doctor->user->name;
// This
$doctor = Doctor::find(1);
$doctor->name;
```

P.S: Didn't know what to put in the title, what should I put instead so it is more relevant to the question?

Comment: If a doctor does not have a user, would you like to still see that doctor in your results?

Comment: A doctor would ALWAYS be related to a user (at least in this case). Please read the comment to the answer done by `Matthew Rath`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can specify default eager loaded relationships using the `$with` property on the model.

```
class Doctor extends Eloquent {

    protected $with = ['user'];

    // ...
}
```

(The property might need to be public, I forget. Laravel will yell at you if it does.)

You will still need to use `$doctor->user->name`, but the relationship will be automatically loaded without you needing to explicitly call it. If you *really* want to use the `$doctor->name` syntax, you could create [Accessors](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) for those column names, which would then fetch and pass the appropriate User relationship columns.

Comment: I ended up using Accessors and $appends and it worked as intended. It even appears in the docs [Appends + Accessors (at the end)](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#converting-to-arrays-or-json).

Comment: didn't know this simply tick and it simply solve my problem

Comment: What if you want to return the user relationship as a resource or resource collection, how would you go about it @Aken Roberts

Answer (score 19):

I ended up using `Accessors` and `$appends` and it worked as intended. It even appears in the docs Appends + Accessors (at the end). Thanks to Cyrode, whom showed me the Accessors (didn't know they exised).

I could've not use the `$appends` array, but you need it if you're returning the model in JSON.

As Jarek Tkaczyk *deczo* suggested, you should use `with` property when you go with this approach, otherwise whenever you load multiple `Doctor` models and call anything `User` related, you end up with a db query (per each `Doctor` instance) -> n+1 issue

Doctor class ended up looking like this:

```
<?php

class Doctor extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'doctors';

    protected $with = ['user'];

    protected $appends = ['first_name','last_name','email','date_of_birth'];

    protected $hidden = ['signature','user'];

    public function user(){

        return $this->belongsTo('User');

    }

    public function getFirstNameAttribute() {

        return $this->user->first_name;

    }

    public function getLastNameAttribute() {

        return $this->user->last_name;

    }

  public function getEmailAttribute() {

      return $this->user->email;

  }

}
```

I had to put `user` inside the `$hidden` array or it would show up whenever I retireved `Doctor` (Besides I only needed some things of `User`, not everything)

Comment: You should use `with` property when you go with this approach, otherwise whenever you load multiple `Doctor` models and call anything `User` related, you end up with a db query (per each Doctor instance) -> n+1 issue

Comment: Thanks Jarek, good suggestion. Will update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way. Is it good design? Maybe, maybe not. Hard to say from your short description.

```
// Doctor model
public function __get($key)
{
    // check deafult behaviour
    if (is_null($value = parent::__get($key))) return $value;

    // if null, let's try related user
    return $this->user->__get($key);
}

public function __set($key, $value)
{
    $user = $this->user;

    // first try user
    if (array_key_exists($key, $user->getAttributes()) || $user->hasSetMutator($key))
    {
        return $user->__set($key, $value);
    }

    // then default
    parent::__set($key, $value);
}
```

This way you can do this:

```
$doctor->name; // returns $doctor->user->name; unless you have accessors for name

$doctor->name = 'Some Name';
// then
$doctor->user->name; // 'Some Name';

// so finally push instead of save, in order to save related user too
$doctor->push();
```

Mind that this is pretty simple example, for brevity. There is a chance, that existing attribute of `Doctor` model is `null`, so `$this->user->__get()` should not be called, for example. So to make it fully reliable, you need to check `hasGetMutator()`, `relations` and so on. Check `Model`s `__get` and `__set` for details.