# Laravel pluck nested collection to root collection

Tags: php, laravel, web, backend, laravel-8

[image: dd(Order)]

I have a data structure like you can see in the picture above.
I want some fields from user field in the root collection, but I don't know how can I can get that.

```php
public function index (Request $request) {
    $draw = $request->get('draw');
    $start = $request->get('start');
    $length = $request->get('length');

    $order = Order::with('user');
    $total_order = $order->count();
    $orders =  Order::with('user')->offset($start)->limit($length)->get();

    /*$draw = ceil($total_order/$length);*/
    return response()->json([
        'draw' => $draw,
        'recordsTotal' => $total_order,
        'recordsFiltered' => $total_order,
        'data' => $orders,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pluck with multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54236337/3578036)

Comment: nope it didn't help

Comment: Can you post the actual and desired result as text instead of an image? Furthermore, I'm not sure if the picture illustrates what is returned by `return response()->json([ ... ]);`.

Comment: Why are you storing `$order` but not using the value?

Comment: Your question is so vague. Your title implies you want to pluck multiple columns from your data, but then you make no attempt in the code to select any number of columns... Using the link I provided, you could do `$orders->pick('count', 'user.name')` to select only the `count` and `user->name` property.

Comment: Thank you for comments, yeah you are right i didn't explained well i edited my question, i want to move name, user_id fields in user to root of collection. I want only one collection not nested collections.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25674143/laravel-whenever-i-return-a-model-always-return-a-relationship-with-it

Comment: Basically i want to flatten that collection.

Comment: I can do what i want with querybuilder methods but i want to be able with eloquent too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flatmap approach seems weird, you have two models Order and Users, either you have to add extra properties to orders on the fly, which is weird in `Laravel` if you want to save the model again. Or you have to convert it to arrays and you loose the Model functionality.

Instead of trying to flatten the user object onto the order. You are already using `with()`, so your user is eager loaded and can rely on that. Instead use `Eloquent` Getters and map your user fields to the order.

```
class Order extends Model
{
    public function getUserNameAttribute() {
        return $this->user->name;
    }
}
```

Eloquent getters function name has to be in the format `getPropertyAttribute`. Now you would be able to access it like so, which also can be done in blade etc.

```
foreach ($orders as $order) {
    $userName = $order->userName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you truly want the related values in the root collection, you could do a left join on the table:

```php
$orders = Order::leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')
```

(Based on the model names, these would be the correct table and column names).

However, like Mrhn just pointed out, it is not very Eloquent-like to try and have data of related tables in the root collection of the main model.

P.S. If you do use the left join, be sure to only select the data you need, otherwise it *will* overwrite Order data (such as `id`)